# Wifi won't connect - Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, network-manager

Ive been scouring the Ubuntu forums for hours trying lots of different things but they all seem to be specific to someone's terminal output, My wifi finds networks but won't connect, Wired Connection is working ok, I have also looked for a linux driver for my specific PCI card but can't seem to find one.

WIFI ADAPTER: Ralink corp. RT3062 Wireless 802.11n 2T/2R

```
iwconfig: 
eth0: no wireless extension
lo: no wireless extension
wlan0: IEEE 802.11bgn --- ESSID: off/any
Mode: Managed --- Access Point: Not-Associated -- Tx-Power=20 dBm
Retry --- long limit: 7 --- RTS thr: off --- Fragment thr: off
Power Managment: off
```

Please request more information if needed.

Update More Info:

**uname -a**

```
Linux Anonymous 3.8.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 1 16:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**dmesg**

```
[    1.607468] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.607473] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: applying AMD SB700/SB800/Hudson-2/3 EHCI dummy qh workaround
[    1.607484] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: debug port 1
[    1.607521] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: irq 17, io mem 0xfe02c000
[    1.618869] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.618901] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.618903] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.618904] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.618906] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.618907] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:12.2
[    1.618993] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.618996] hub 1-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    1.619092] ehci-pci 0000:00:13.2: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.619097] ehci-pci 0000:00:13.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.619101] ehci-pci 0000:00:13.2: applying AMD SB700/SB800/Hudson-2/3 EHCI dummy qh workaround
[    1.619112] ehci-pci 0000:00:13.2: debug port 1
[    1.619144] ehci-pci 0000:00:13.2: irq 19, io mem 0xfe029000
[    1.630845] ehci-pci 0000:00:13.2: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.630876] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.630877] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.630879] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.630880] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.630881] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:13.2
[    1.630951] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.630953] hub 2-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    1.631034] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    1.631040] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.631061] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.0: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.631064] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.631087] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.0: irq 16, io mem 0xfe02e000
[    1.690645] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.690647] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.690649] usb usb3: Product: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.690650] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ohci_hcd
[    1.690651] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:12.0
[    1.690719] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.690725] hub 3-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    1.690794] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.1: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.690797] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    1.690809] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.1: irq 16, io mem 0xfe02d000
[    1.750463] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.750465] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.750467] usb usb4: Product: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.750468] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ohci_hcd
[    1.750469] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:12.1
[    1.750538] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.750543] hub 4-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    1.750611] ohci_hcd 0000:00:13.0: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.750615] ohci_hcd 0000:00:13.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 5
[    1.750638] ohci_hcd 0000:00:13.0: irq 18, io mem 0xfe02b000
[    1.810284] usb usb5: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.810286] usb usb5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.810287] usb usb5: Product: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.810289] usb usb5: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ohci_hcd
[    1.810290] usb usb5: SerialNumber: 0000:00:13.0
[    1.810358] hub 5-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.810363] hub 5-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    1.810434] ohci_hcd 0000:00:13.1: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.810438] ohci_hcd 0000:00:13.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 6
[    1.810449] ohci_hcd 0000:00:13.1: irq 18, io mem 0xfe02a000
[    1.870109] usb usb6: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.870111] usb usb6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.870112] usb usb6: Product: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.870114] usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ohci_hcd
[    1.870115] usb usb6: SerialNumber: 0000:00:13.1
[    1.870190] hub 6-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.870195] hub 6-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    1.870264] ohci_hcd 0000:00:14.5: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.870267] ohci_hcd 0000:00:14.5: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 7
[    1.870278] ohci_hcd 0000:00:14.5: irq 18, io mem 0xfe028000
[    1.929926] usb usb7: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.929930] usb usb7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.929934] usb usb7: Product: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.929959] usb usb7: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ohci_hcd
[    1.929961] usb usb7: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.5
[    1.930033] hub 7-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.930038] hub 7-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    1.930089] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.930122] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.930125] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 8
[    1.930227] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.930263] usb usb8: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.930265] usb usb8: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.930266] usb usb8: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.930267] usb usb8: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic xhci_hcd
[    1.930269] usb usb8: SerialNumber: 0000:02:00.0
[    1.930318] xHCI xhci_add_endpoint called for root hub
[    1.930320] xHCI xhci_check_bandwidth called for root hub
[    1.930332] hub 8-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.930337] hub 8-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    1.930379] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.930382] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 9
[    1.930398] usb usb9: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.930399] usb usb9: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.930401] usb usb9: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.930402] usb usb9: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic xhci_hcd
[    1.930403] usb usb9: SerialNumber: 0000:02:00.0
[    1.930447] xHCI xhci_add_endpoint called for root hub
[    1.930448] xHCI xhci_check_bandwidth called for root hub
[    1.930460] hub 9-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.930464] hub 9-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    1.930577] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.930584] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 10
[    1.930690] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.930731] usb usb10: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.930733] usb usb10: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.930735] usb usb10: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.930736] usb usb10: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic xhci_hcd
[    1.930738] usb usb10: SerialNumber: 0000:04:00.0
[    1.930791] xHCI xhci_add_endpoint called for root hub
[    1.930792] xHCI xhci_check_bandwidth called for root hub
[    1.930808] hub 10-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.930813] hub 10-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    1.930863] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.930866] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 11
[    1.930882] usb usb11: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.930884] usb usb11: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.930885] usb usb11: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.930886] usb usb11: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic xhci_hcd
[    1.930888] usb usb11: SerialNumber: 0000:04:00.0
[    1.930934] xHCI xhci_add_endpoint called for root hub
[    1.930935] xHCI xhci_check_bandwidth called for root hub
[    1.930949] hub 11-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.930953] hub 11-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    1.931090] i8042: PNP: No PS/2 controller found. Probing ports directly.
[    1.963590] i8042: Failed to disable AUX port, but continuing anyway... Is this a SiS?
[    1.963591] i8042: If AUX port is really absent please use the 'i8042.noaux' option
[    2.213155] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    2.213245] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    2.213355] rtc_cmos 00:04: RTC can wake from S4
[    2.213453] rtc_cmos 00:04: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[    2.213483] rtc0: alarms up to one month, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[    2.213548] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    2.213599] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.23.1-ioctl (2012-12-18) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    2.213638] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    2.213694] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    2.213698] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    2.213699] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[    2.213864] ashmem: initialized
[    2.213950] TCP: cubic registered
[    2.214019] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.214141] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.214147] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    2.214394] Loading module verification certificates
[    2.215129] MODSIGN: Loaded cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: 4fb521df0b0fa81f775431361b8076d5d0f1869a'
[    2.215136] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.217769] Key type trusted registered
[    2.219501] Key type encrypted registered
[    2.221299] rtc_cmos 00:04: setting system clock to 2013-10-03 15:35:21 UTC (1380814521)
[    2.221335] powernow-k8: this CPU is not supported anymore, using acpi-cpufreq instead.
[    2.222140] acpi-cpufreq: overriding BIOS provided _PSD data
[    2.222320] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    2.222321] EDD information not available.
[    2.224333] Freeing unused kernel memory: 992k freed
[    2.224504] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 12288k
[    2.228992] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1176k freed
[    2.232929] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1080k freed
[    2.243505] udevd[109]: starting version 175
[    2.267637] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[    2.268090] ahci 0000:00:11.0: version 3.0
[    2.268385] ahci 0000:00:11.0: AHCI 0001.0100 32 slots 4 ports 3 Gbps 0xf impl SATA mode
[    2.268389] ahci 0000:00:11.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf ilck pm led clo pmp pio slum part ccc 
[    2.268729] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    2.268945] r8169 0000:03:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.268959] wmi: Mapper loaded
[    2.269531] scsi0 : ahci
[    2.269651] scsi1 : ahci
[    2.270660] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: RTL8168evl/8111evl at 0xffffc90001872000, 90:2b:34:99:02:f3, XID 0c900800 IRQ 46
[    2.270663] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    2.271131] scsi2 : ahci
[    2.271256] scsi3 : ahci
[    2.271294] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m1024@0xfe02f000 port 0xfe02f100 irq 22
[    2.271298] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m1024@0xfe02f000 port 0xfe02f180 irq 22
[    2.271300] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m1024@0xfe02f000 port 0xfe02f200 irq 22
[    2.271303] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m1024@0xfe02f000 port 0xfe02f280 irq 22
[    2.279556] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    2.281031] scsi4 : pata_atiixp
[    2.287482] scsi5 : pata_atiixp
[    2.287825] ata5: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xfa00 irq 14
[    2.287827] ata6: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xfa08 irq 15
[    2.299045] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[    2.299581] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 1 (10.10.2010).
[    2.299583] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[    2.299585] [drm] Initialized radeon 1.33.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[    2.465133] ata6.00: ATA-8: WDC WD10EADX-00TDHB0, 77.04D77, max UDMA/133
[    2.465136] ata6.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
[    2.465154] ata6.01: ATAPI: TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-222BB, SB00, max UDMA/100
[    2.481165] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    2.496663] ata6.01: configured for UDMA/100
[    2.552143] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 4218.660 MHz
[    2.552154] Switching to clocksource tsc
[    2.560109] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    2.588037] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.588081] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.592023] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.592070] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.592305] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD10EADX-00T 77.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.592413] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[    2.592457] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    2.592475] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    2.592478] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    2.592509] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.595006] scsi 5:0:1:0: CD-ROM            TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-222BB  SB00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.623589] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 16x/16x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    2.623595] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    2.623784] sr 5:0:1:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    2.623847] sr 5:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    2.631839]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
[    2.634092] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.692705] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5567
[    2.692708] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.692710] usb 2-4: Product: Cruzer Blade
[    2.692711] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[    2.692712] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 20051739220C80C0562B
[    2.694391] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[    2.694517] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-4:1.0
[    2.694564] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.694566] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[    2.954916] usb 5-3: new low-speed USB device number 2 using ohci_hcd
[    3.131394] usb 5-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1c4f, idProduct=0002
[    3.131401] usb 5-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.131406] usb 5-3: Product: USB Keykoard
[    3.131410] usb 5-3: Manufacturer: USB
[    3.147361] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    3.147364] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    3.149515] input: USB USB Keykoard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-3/5-3:1.0/input/input2
[    3.149872] hid-generic 0003:1C4F:0002.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [USB USB Keykoard] on usb-0000:00:13.0-3/input0
[    3.150031] input: USB USB Keykoard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-3/5-3:1.1/input/input3
[    3.150095] hid-generic 0003:1C4F:0002.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [USB USB Keykoard] on usb-0000:00:13.0-3/input1
[    3.265976] usb 3-2: new low-speed USB device number 2 using ohci_hcd
[    3.430487] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=093a, idProduct=2521
[    3.430495] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.430500] usb 3-2: Product: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[    3.440743] input: USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/input/input4
[    3.440839] hid-generic 0003:093A:2521.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input0
[    3.689354] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Blade     1.26 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    3.689826] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[    3.691091] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 7821312 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 GB/3.72 GiB)
[    3.692165] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    3.692169] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[    3.693092] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.697979]  sdb: sdb1
[    3.700578] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci_hcd
[    3.701453] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[    3.873058] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52e
[    3.873060] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.873061] usb 3-3: Product: USB Receiver
[    3.873061] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    3.881196] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/input/input5
[    3.881270] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52E.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:12.0-3/input0
[    3.886310] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.1/input/input6
[    3.886531] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52E.0005: input,hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:12.0-3/input1
[   16.349513] bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
[   16.514292] bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
[   22.566523] EXT4-fs (dm-1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[   22.566526] EXT4-fs (dm-1): write access will be enabled during recovery
[   23.641340] EXT4-fs (dm-1): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[   23.641346] EXT4-fs (dm-1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 44564502
[   23.641368] EXT4-fs (dm-1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 44564501
[   23.641374] EXT4-fs (dm-1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 44564500
[   23.641380] EXT4-fs (dm-1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 40109593
[   23.641409] EXT4-fs (dm-1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 44564499
[   23.641415] EXT4-fs (dm-1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 44564498
[   23.641421] EXT4-fs (dm-1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 2621752
[   23.641458] EXT4-fs (dm-1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 2621651
[   23.641468] EXT4-fs (dm-1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 44564497
[   23.641479] EXT4-fs (dm-1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 44564496
[   23.641490] EXT4-fs (dm-1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 44564495
[   23.641500] EXT4-fs (dm-1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 44564494
[   23.641515] EXT4-fs (dm-1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 44564493
[   23.641525] EXT4-fs (dm-1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 2621640
[   23.641535] EXT4-fs (dm-1): 14 orphan inodes deleted
[   23.641536] EXT4-fs (dm-1): recovery complete
[   23.773271] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   26.714729] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   27.014172] udevd[504]: starting version 175
[   27.343988] EXT4-fs (dm-1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   28.564859] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   29.267383] parport_pc 00:08: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
[   29.267435] parport0: PC-style at 0x378, irq 7 [PCSPP,TRISTATE]
[   29.363116] lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).
[   29.425148] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   29.426077] MCE: In-kernel MCE decoding enabled.
[   29.504277] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[   29.590044] AMD64 EDAC driver v3.4.0
[   29.590065] EDAC amd64: DRAM ECC disabled.
[   29.590071] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
[   29.590071]  Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
[   29.590071]  (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[   29.596682] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000b00-0x0000000000000b07 SystemIO conflicts with Region \SOR1 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   29.596687] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   29.612131] microcode: CPU0: patch_level=0x06000626
[   29.701156] sp5100_tco: SP5100/SB800 TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v0.05
[   29.701195] sp5100_tco: PCI Revision ID: 0x3c
[   29.701211] sp5100_tco: failed to find MMIO address, giving up.
[   30.001882] microcode: CPU0: new patch_level=0x06000629
[   30.001892] microcode: CPU1: patch_level=0x06000626
[   30.001900] microcode: CPU2: patch_level=0x06000626
[   30.012295] microcode: CPU2: new patch_level=0x06000629
[   30.012304] microcode: CPU3: patch_level=0x06000626
[   30.012601] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[   31.853776] kvm: disabled by bios
[   31.855990] kvm: disabled by bios
[   31.860270] kvm: disabled by bios
[   31.863998] kvm: disabled by bios
[   31.976456] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   32.469245] input: HDA ATI SB Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input7
[   32.469319] input: HDA ATI SB Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input8
[   32.469379] input: HDA ATI SB Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input9
[   32.469438] input: HDA ATI SB Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input10
[   32.469496] input: HDA ATI SB Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input11
[   32.469779] hda-intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle VGA-switcheroo audio client
[   32.469838] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[   32.572904] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input12
[   33.004984] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[   33.712398] EXT2-fs (sda1): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
[   33.736739] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   33.736741] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   33.736743] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   33.736744] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   33.736746] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   33.736747] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   33.736748] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   34.113263] type=1400 audit(1380814553.485:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=886 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.113313] type=1400 audit(1380814553.485:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1023 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.113321] type=1400 audit(1380814553.485:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=905 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.113712] type=1400 audit(1380814553.485:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=886 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.113760] type=1400 audit(1380814553.485:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1023 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.113767] type=1400 audit(1380814553.485:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=905 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.113952] type=1400 audit(1380814553.485:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=886 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.114011] type=1400 audit(1380814553.485:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1023 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.114017] type=1400 audit(1380814553.485:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=905 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   35.349305] init: failsafe main process (1060) killed by TERM signal
[   36.283172] type=1400 audit(1380814555.661:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1148 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   37.461643] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   37.461658] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   37.461660] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   37.461666] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   37.461668] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   37.461673] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   37.566494] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   37.566502] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   37.566503] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   37.744700] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   37.744703] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   37.744710] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   38.350122] init: avahi-cups-reload main process (1271) terminated with status 1
[   38.619045] vboxdrv: Found 4 processor cores.
[   38.619274] vboxdrv: fAsync=0 offMin=0x60b offMax=0x4018
[   38.619748] vboxdrv: TSC mode is 'synchronous', kernel timer mode is 'normal'.
[   38.619750] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 4.2.10_Ubuntu (interface 0x001a0004).
[   38.982517] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[   41.236237] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (1518) terminated with status 1
[   42.158520] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
[   42.158555] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   42.158604] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
[   42.158803] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   42.292268] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   42.292463] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   42.850789] Adding 16756732k swap on /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16756732k 
[   43.657550] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up
[   43.657557] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   76.699326] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[   76.895853] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
[  121.622347] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
[  126.439702] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  126.570751] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up
[  126.570760] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  276.381016] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  280.173733] wlan0: authenticate with 00:26:4d:6f:b6:90
[  280.221303] wlan0: send auth to 00:26:4d:6f:b6:90 (try 1/3)
[  280.229562] wlan0: authenticated
[  280.229708] rt2800pci 0000:05:06.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  280.229722] rt2800pci 0000:05:06.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  280.233187] wlan0: associate with 00:26:4d:6f:b6:90 (try 1/3)
[  280.260115] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:26:4d:6f:b6:90 (capab=0x401 status=0 aid=2)
[  280.260310] wlan0: associated
[  280.260341] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  280.260424] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
[  280.263538] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DE
[  280.263540] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  280.263542] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[  280.263543] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[  280.263544] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[  280.263546] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm)
```

**Note: The network I am trying to connect to is an Unsecure Network**

Comment: I'm seeing that it becomes associated, you sure that the problem is with the driver instead of the Network Manager?